# Codeigniter : Default libraries are not accessble after calling custom library

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to verify log in data so I've created a custom library where it checks the user type and redirects login pages accordingly.

Everything works but the problem is every other library I try to access inside my controller are not accessible and I have to add the those libraries before accessing the my custom library.

This works

```
public function __construct() 
    {
        parent:: __construct();
        $this->load->model("Delivery_agents_model");
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->library('access');
    }
```

but this doesn't work.

```
<?php if( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Access extends CI_Controller {
    public function verify($access) 
    {
        if ( (array) $access !== $access )
        {
            switch ($access) 
            {
                case 'admin':
                    if (! $this->session->userdata('admin_logged_in'))
                    {
                        redirect(base_url('admin/login'));                      
                    }
                    break;
                case 'delivery_agent':
                    if (! $this->session->userdata('delivery_agent_logged_in'))
                    {
                        redirect(base_url('delivery_agent/login'));
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $logged_in = FALSE;

            foreach ($access as $access_type) 
            {
                switch ($access_type) 
                {
                    case 'admin':
                        if ($this->session->userdata('admin_logged_in'))
                        {
                            $logged_in = TRUE;
                        }
                        break;
                    case 'delivery_agent':
                        if ($this->session->userdata('delivery_agent_logged_in'))
                        {
                            $logged_in = TRUE;
                        }
                        break;
                }

            }

            if (! $logged_in)
            {
                switch ($access[0]) 
                {
                    case 'admin':
                        redirect(base_url('admin/login'));
                        break;
                    case 'delivery_agent':
                        redirect(base_url('delivery_agent/login'));
                        break;
                }
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

I've to access controller as I'm checking the session data.

Please suggest me if I'm doing or anything wrong with it.

Why the default libraries are not loading which has been defined after calling the function in the class.

Here is how I'm calling the function from the custom library.

```
$this->access->verify(array('admin'));
```

Here is the error I'm getting

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Delivery_agents::$form_validation

Filename: controllers/delivery_agents.php

Line Number: 104


Fatal error: Call to a member function set_rules() on a non-object in /var/www/project/application/controllers/delivery_agents.php on line 104
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is you are extending CI_Controller in your library. Because if your library extends CI_Controller. That means that you are actually extending the functionality of the controllers.

use

```
class Access {
```

instead of

```
class Access extends CI_Controller {
```

And add this following Constructor to your library

```
function __construct()
{
    $this->ci =& get_instance();
}
```

Then after adding constructor you can use `$this->ci` instead of `$this` in your library. For instance:

```
$this->ci->session->userdata('admin_logged_in')
```

For more information [Libraries](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html)

Comment: Thanks ! Perfect answer. Initially I've added the $this->ci =& get_instance(); but not in the constructor so it was not working.